# run a search over the items of a list, and save each search into a file

Tags: python, regex, file, for-loop, pattern-matching

I have a `data.dat` file that has 3 columns: The 3rd column is just the numbers `1` to `6` repeated again and again:

( In reality, column 3 has numbers from `1` to `1917`, but for a minimal working example, let's stick to `1` to `6` )

```
# Title
127.26 134.85 1
127.26 135.76 2
127.26 135.76 3
127.26 160.97 4
127.26 160.97 5
127.26 201.49 6
125.88 132.67 1
125.88 140.07 2
125.88 140.07 3
125.88 165.05 4
125.88 165.05 5
125.88 203.06 6
137.20 140.97 1
137.20 140.97 2
137.20 148.21 3
137.20 155.37 4
137.20 155.37 5
137.20 184.07 6
```

I would like to:

1) extract the lines that contain `1` in the 3rd column and save them to a file called `mode_1.dat`.

2) extract the lines that contain `2` in the 3rd column and save them to a file called `mode_2.dat`.

3) extract the lines that contain `3` in the 3rd column and save them to a file called `mode_3.dat`.

.

.

.

6) extract the lines that contain `6` in the 3rd column and save them to a file called `mode_6.dat`.

In order to accomplish this, I have:

a)  defined a variable `factor = 6`

a) created a `one_to_factor` list that has numbers `1` to `6`

b) The `re.search` statement is in charge of extracting the lines for each value of `one_to_factor`. `%s` are the `i` inside the `one_to_factor` list

c) `append` these results to an empty `LINES` list.

However, this does not work. I cannot manage to extract the lines that contain `i` in the 3rd column and save them to a file called `mode_i.dat`

I would appreciate if you could help me.

```
factor = 6
one_to_factor = range(1,factor+1)

LINES = []
f_2 = open('data.dat', 'r')
for line in f_2:
   for i in one_to_factor:
     if re.search(r' \b%s$' %i , line):       
        print 'line = ', line
        LINES.append(line)

        print 'LINES =' , LINES
```

Comment: What exactly does not work ? Do you have an error or something ?

Comment: For the first part of your question you can do it with following regex:

r = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', line) => [127.26, 134.85, 1]. [link to regex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F)&test_string=127.26%20134.85%201&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

- no regexes, just use `str.split()` to split according to whitespace
- use last item (the digit) of the current line to generate the filename
- use a dictionary to open the file the first time, and reuse the handle for subsequent matches (write title line at file open)
- close all handles in the end

code:

```
title_line="# Vol \t Freq \t Mod \n"
handles = dict()
next(f_2) # skip title
for line in f_2:
        toks = line.split()
        filename = "mode_{}.dat".format(toks[-1])
        # create files first time id encountered
        if filename in handles:
            pass
        else:
            handles[filename] = open(filename,"w")
            handles[filename].write(title_line)  # write title
        handles[filename].write(line)

# close all files
for v in handles.values():
    v.close()
```

EDIT: that's the fastest way but the problem is if you have too many suffixes (like in your real example), you'll get "too many open files" exception. So for this case, there's a slightly less efficient method but which works too:

```
import glob,os
# pre-processing: cleanup old files if any
for f in glob.glob("mode_*.dat"):
   os.remove(f)

next(f_2) # skip title
s = set()
title_line="# Vol \t Freq \t Mod \n"

for line in f_2:
        toks = line.split()
        filename = "mode_{}.dat".format(toks[-1])    
        with open(filename,"a") as f:
            if filename in s:
                pass
            else:
                s.add(filename)
                f.write(title_line)
            f.write(line)
```

It basically opens as append mode, writes the lines, and closes the file.

(the `set` is used to detect first write in this file, so title can be written before the data)

There's a directory cleanup first to ensure that no data is left from a previous computation (append mode expects that no file exists, and if input data set changes, there's a possibility that there's an indentifier not present in the new dataset, so there would be an "orphan" file remaining from previous run)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, `next(lines)` gives this error: `name 'lines' is not defined`. In addition, `for l in lines:` should be `for l in line:`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Another minor thing is that it should be `handles[filename].write(line)` instead of `handles[filename].write(l)`. Correcting this line, the script works for the above minimal working example. This MWE has column 3 as `1 ... 20`, **however**, the real file has column 3 as `1 ... 1917` (as stated at the beginning of my first original post in the third line). The problem is that when running this script over the real file, it prompts: `File "script.py", line " handles[filename] = open(filename,"w")", in <module> IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'mode_1020.dat'`

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I would need to add the same title to all the `mode_X.dat` files. I have tried many things... the most accurate was:  `with open (filename,"a") as f1, open(filename,"w") as f:` and in an indented block, the following two statements: `f.write('# Vol \t Freq \t Mod \n ')` `f1.write(line)`. The title was added on each `mode_X.dat` file, but only the last `line` was written to each file. Could you help me to add the same title `# Vol \t Freq \t Mod \n ` on each `mode_X.dat` file ? Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you so much for the support. It is amazing that the only way to include the title before the data was by suing a `set`. Very good idea. However, I would like to learn as much as possible and not just stay in the "how-to". I am really new to the use of `set`: I have been searching thoroughly but I don't understand very well their relation with dictionaries and lists and in which case we should use `set` rather than a list or a dictionary. Do you know any link that explains this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of looping on you one_to_factor, you can get the index in one step :

```
index = line[-1] # Last character on the line
```

Then, you can check if index is in your one_to_factor list.

You should created a dictionary of lists to store your lines.
Something like :

```
{ "1" : [line1, line7, ...],
  "2" : ....
}
```

And then you can use the key of the dictionnary to create the file and populate it with lines.

Comment: Doesn't that assume the third column is only a single digit, whereas OP says it actually goes to `1917`?